# Zipping a number of potentially large files in chunks to avoid large memory consumption

Tags: c#

I am working on an application that can take a list of file keys to files on AWS S3 as input and then create a zip file back on AWS S3 with all of those files inside. The compression part does not matter - the important part is to have a single zip file containing all of the other files.

To be able to run the application on a server without a lot of memory or file storage space, I was thinking of using the API that allows fetching a byte range from a file on S3: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html for downloading the files in chunks, and then add them to the zip file and upload the chunk using the multipart upload API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html

I have tried to make a small sample app, that will simulate how it could work (without actually calling the S3 APIs yet), but it gets stuck on this line: "await zipStream.WriteAsync(inBuffer, 0, currentChunk);"

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    const int ChunkSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;

    using (var fileOutputStream = new FileStream("/Users/SPE/Downloads/BG_K01.zip", FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (var fileInputStream = File.Open("/Users/SPE/Downloads/BG_K01.rvt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            long fileSize = new FileInfo("/Users/SPE/Downloads/BG_K01.rvt").Length;
            int readBytes = 0;
            using (AnonymousPipeServerStream pipeServer = new AnonymousPipeServerStream())
            {
                using (AnonymousPipeClientStream pipeClient = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(pipeServer.GetClientHandleAsString()))
                {
                    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(pipeServer, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                    {
                        var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("BG_K01.rvt", CompressionLevel.NoCompression);
                        using (var zipStream = zipEntry.Open())
                        {
                            // Simulate receiving and sending a chunk of bytes
                            while (readBytes < fileSize)
                            {
                                var currentChunk = (int)Math.Min(ChunkSize, fileSize - readBytes);
                                var inBuffer = new byte[currentChunk];
                                var outBuffer = new byte[currentChunk];

                                await fileInputStream.ReadAsync(inBuffer, 0, currentChunk);
                                await zipStream.WriteAsync(inBuffer, 0, currentChunk);


                                await pipeClient.ReadAsync(outBuffer, 0, currentChunk);
                                await fileOutputStream.WriteAsync(outBuffer, 0, currentChunk);

                                readBytes += currentChunk;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am also not sure if using the pipe streams is the best way to do this, but my hope is that they will release any memory consumed once the stream has been read, and thereby keep the memory consumption very low.

Does anybody know why writing to the zipStream hangs?

Comment: so the point of a stream is that push/pull. So if you ask for a buffer to be filled with a certain amount of bytes, that is all that will be brought in,  and soon as you put it in the stream as long as it is filestream, the operating system will take care for writing it to disk

Comment: but it gets stuck when writing to the zipStream - not a filestream. It does not get to the pipeClient.ReadAsync call

Comment: Have you looked at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.createfromdirectory?view=netframework-4.8 once you've downloaded all the files, just call that function and it will zip the entire directory. then you can uploaded that as a filestream. you can set a flag to include the base directory or not

Comment: this way it avoids your complicated stream in stream in stream scenario

Comment: But that would require enough disk space to store all the files in the server, and I would prefer to not have that requirement if at all possible

Comment: yeah but it is either disk space or memory?

Comment: The idea was to only fetch small parts of the files at a time, and then upload those parts before fetching the next small part - meaning I would only ever have to keep the "small part" in memory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199290/discussion-between-callum-linington-and-soren-pedersen).